# Flutter, Best way to optimise material sizes based on screen resolution/dpi?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am currently coding a android application using flutter, dart. I have a settings page that gives the user the ability to change theme. I have created 7 identical Raw Material Button in the shape of a circle. I have been reading around the best way to size the circle base on the users resolution/dpi.

**themeButton.dart:**

```
final _themeColour;
final VoidCallback _onPressed;

ThemeButton(this._themeColour, this._onPressed);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  double ratio = width/height;

  return RawMaterialButton (
    shape: CircleBorder(),
    fillColor: _themeColour,
    elevation: 0.0,
    highlightElevation: 0.0,
    onPressed: () => _onPressed(),
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,  
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: width * ratio * 0.2),
  );
}
```

At the moment I currently take the users device width and then size the button from that. When I try to look this up, everywhere talks about Pixel Density, however we I tried to use the dpi value as a multiplier the circles were extremely large on high dpi devices.

Using the device width works to a certain extent, however I would like to know if there is a preferred standard to completing this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter handles high dpi automatically for you; see the [devicePixelRatio documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html).

Multiplying by DPI will do it twice (which is why you're seeing them be larger on high dpi devices), whereas if you just set a width that happens automatically. What doesn't happen automatically is resizing to different aspect ratios, but it seems as though you've already come up with a solution to that. I'm not sure if there's anything else you're trying to do that doesn't accomplish - let me know and maybe I can help.

For anyone else dealing with a problem like this, the flutter wiki [has an entry](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Creating-Responsive-Apps) that might be helpful.